# Is there a function like withoutOverlapping() but like "Don't overlap if 5 commands are running" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, scheduling

I'm using Laravel's scheduler to run some commands, but sometimes the command takes a long time and I wan't to make sure it does not spam commands to my server, so I'm looking to somehow do "Don't run if 5 is running atm.

Answer (score 0):

**Be smart when deciding the frequency:**

You can define the frequency of a scheduled task using multiple methods.
See [Schedule Frequency Options](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#schedule-frequency-options)

> ->everyMinute();  Run the task every minute
>
> ->everyFiveMinutes();  Run the task every five minutes
>
> ->everyTenMinutes();   Run the task every ten minutes ...

These methods may be combined with additional constraints to create even more finely tuned schedules that only run on certain days of the week:

> ->weekdays(); Limit the task to weekdays
>
> ->weekends(); Limit the task to weekends ..

**You can daisy chain like below:**

```
$schedule->call(function () {
    //
})->weekly()->mondays()->at('13:00');
```

So you should decide carefully how and when you want to run your commands. Don't run every command at the same interval.

**Finally:**

If you still can't avoid having multiple commands running at the same interval, then you can specify them to run without overlapping (i.e not at the same time):

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: I'm running a command when a new user was created, it's importing data from a API. If a lot of users creates at the same time, it could do 100x commands, and it will make the api get spammed. As it does take sometimes 10-20 min to get all the data. 

So I'm looking for somehow to "throttle" it, so it wont' open 100x commands at once, but maybe only 5-10 at once.

Comment: @Klaus `withoutOverlapping()` is meant to take care of the exact scenario you are talking about.

Comment: Yes, I know but I wan't to run 5-10 of the same command at the same time not only one :)